# WPF two way data binding with parameters but different functionality for each direction

Tags: wpf, 2-way-object-databinding

I have four text boxes which represents parts of a single string and would like to have a converter to implement two way binding, with a parameter to identify the string part.

I am working on an IP address control, which comprises of 4 text boxes to represent the 4 parts with in the IP address. For each text box, I bind to separate properties, then perform translation into a single IP address string using code behind.

i.e. when the user inputs a value into a part this gets inserted into the IP address string and when the IP address changes, a property notification causes all 4 parts to retrieve their values from the IP address string.

I would like to avoid code duplication and have a binding with a parameter to identify the IP address part and can partially do this using a converter. i.e. when a text box property notification occurs, the parameter is used to extract the correct part from the IP address.

I currently have the following

```
        <TextBox Name="ippart1"
                 Text="{Binding Text1}">
        <TextBox Name="ippart2"
                 Text="{Binding Text2}">
        <TextBox Name="ippart3"
                 Text="{Binding Text3}">
        <TextBox Name="ippart3"
                 Text="{Binding Text4}">
```

And would like to have something like

```
        <TextBox Name="ippart1"
                 Text="{Binding IpAddress
                 Converter={StaticResource IpAddressPartConverter},
                 ConverterParameter=0}}">
        <TextBox Name="ippart2"
                 Text="{Binding IpAddress
                 Converter={StaticResource IpAddressPartConverter},
                 ConverterParameter=1}}">
        <TextBox Name="ippart3"
                 Text="{Binding IpAddress
                 Converter={StaticResource IpAddressPartConverter},
                 ConverterParameter=2}}">
        <TextBox Name="ippart4"
                 Text="{Binding IpAddress
                 Converter={StaticResource IpAddressPartConverter},
                 ConverterParameter=3}}">
```

I could add a converter to retrieve a part from IpAddress (simplified code shown below).

```
public class IpAddressPartConverter : IValueConverter
{
    const int cIpComponents = 4;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string retStr = "";
        int ipPartId = 0;
        string ipAddr = value as string;
        string[] strArray = ipAddr.Split('.');

        Int32.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out ipPartId)

        return strArray[ipPartId];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Wont work because we dont have the rest of the current ip address string. 
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that the converter does not work in the opposite direction because of missing information, i.e. when the user changes a part value, even though the part id and the new part string is known, the other three parts are not, and so a new IP address string cannot be created.

Is it possible to have a different binding for each direction? Or is there a better solution to my problem?

Comment: A better solution would be a view model class (e.g. IpAddress) with four string properties.

Comment: I am already binding to a view model class which has four string properties Text1, Text2, Text3 & Text4. If possible I would like to optimise to use a single binding with a parameter.

Comment: IMO, your question proves that this wouldn't be an optimization.